# python: import error: no module named

Tags: python, import

Out of nowhere my scripts aren't finding locations anymore, that worked previously.
The only thing i changed was to add a environmental variable in Windows because i didn't get access python via the command line. But also after deleting it and resetting the "PATH" variable the problem is the same.

The error only occurs for modules in my project directory which i import via "from... import..."
no problem with "import sys" and so on.

I don't understand what's going on. I use eclipse and Python 2.7.

Update: I "auto configured" in the interpreter menu so that PYTHONPATH was rebuilt, i used File-->Restart but i won't damn work! I even removed the system environmental variable from windows. What is wrong with my setup?

Update2: Now i even reinstalled Eclipse but the f***ing errormessage is still there. It's driving me crazy! Anybody with more tips?

Update3: The problem occured after my laptop shut down because the battery was low. During that it was executing a script. Maybe it has sth. to do with the forced shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found the solution.
Somehow the inner structure of my project got messed up, that the relative path in "from main.path1.path2 import ..." wasn't valid anymore.
Either it worked like "from path1.path2 import..." or (what i did) I created a project and included again the folder structure, but in the way that it works.